# Arrowheads are wrong color in svg graphic

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have created a svg graphic with inkscape and use it in my LaTeX document. The graphic has a couple colorful lines with corresponding colorful arrowheads. Unfortunately pdflatex seems to arbitrarily assign the colors to the arrowheads. Exporting the svg to png in inkscape results in the correct arrowheadcolors, but then of course my math looks ugly. Has anyone experienced the same and knows of a way to get the correct arrowhead colors? There are already two different colors, so it's not like all arrowheads are treated the same.

Here is my minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includesvg{arrowhead}
\caption{wrong colors of arrowheads in svg version}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{pngarrowhead}
\caption{correct colors in png version}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the resulting pdf (screenshot thereof)

[image: produced pdf]

Here the png exported with inkscape (pngarrowhead.png)

[image: pngarrowhead.png]

And here is the [original svg file](https://mega.nz/file/E8UBTQDZ#TaKhDsXFNXqSNrQX1CJ03t2MctGLyN-e8NYdDel5SmM). Sorry, but I cannot input it here directly, so I share it via a filehoster.

```
<svg width="98.852mm" height="46.58mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 98.852 46.58" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
  <marker id="Arrow1Mend" overflow="visible" orient="auto">
   <path transform="matrix(-.4 0 0 -.4 -4 0)" d="m0 0 5-5-17.5 5 17.5 5z" fill="context-stroke" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="context-stroke" stroke-width="1pt"/>
  </marker>
  <marker id="Arrow1Mstart" overflow="visible" orient="auto">
   <path transform="matrix(.4 0 0 .4 4 0)" d="m0 0 5-5-17.5 5 17.5 5z" fill="context-stroke" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="context-stroke" stroke-width="1pt"/>
  </marker>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(-35.241 -73.283)">
  <path d="m37.042 119.06 47.625-21.167" fill="#0f0" marker-start="url(#Arrow1Mstart)" stop-color="#000000" stroke="#008000" stroke-dasharray="8, 8" style="font-variation-settings:normal"/>
  <g>
   <path d="m84.667 95.25-47.625-21.167" fill="none" marker-end="url(#Arrow1Mend)" stroke="#f0f"/>
   <path d="m84.667 95.25 47.625-21.167" fill="none" marker-end="url(#Arrow1Mend)" stroke="#00f"/>
   <path d="m84.667 95.25 47.625 21.167" fill="#0f0" marker-end="url(#Arrow1Mend)" stroke="#0f0"/>
   <path d="m37.042 116.42 47.625-21.167" fill="#f00" marker-end="url(#Arrow1Mend)" stop-color="#000000" stroke="#f00" style="-inkscape-stroke:none;font-variation-settings:normal"/>
  </g>
  <text x="72.760414" y="82.020821" fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10.583px" letter-spacing="0px" stroke-width=".26458" word-spacing="0px" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="72.760414" y="82.020821" stroke-width=".26458">$x^2$</tspan></text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: something odd with the svg arrow heads, [firefox doesn't show heads at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j60ee.png) ...  [chrome shows them all black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbwZ5.png)

Comment: I added the svg to your question (not sure why you said you needed a file share, it is not very big?)

Comment: Yes, I noticed the weird firefox and chrome behavior as well. Gnome image viewer shows it correctly though. And what puzzles me is that latex shows 2 different arrow head colors, instead of the requested 4.
Ah, yeah, thanks for embedding the file. Just did not occur to me.

Comment: Optimizing the svg before saving makes it even smaller, but does not change the result in latex. The plain svg output option does not help either.

Comment: Well, the export to pdf is flawed, so probably an issue which should be reported to the Inkscape team

Comment: @mrpiggi Indeed, haven't even thought of checking that first. So used to the great svg package and inkscape just working that it completely threw me off.

Answer (score 2):

As mrpiggi correctly suggested, this is a [known issue](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/2545) in inkscape.
There is also a workaround listed, which is quite simple.

When selecting a marker for the path (like the arrow head in my example), be sure to always choose a fresh arrow marker from the drop down list, and not a previously used arrow marker which gets conveniently listed on top of the list.
To fix broken documents, simply select fresh arrow marker for all arrows in the document.

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape 1.2 if you save files as SVG version 1.1 you can fix the strange behavior by ticking the option under Preferences > Input/Output > SVG export > SVG 2 to SVG 1.1 use correct marker direction and use correct marker colors. This fixed the arrowhead color problem and arrowheads not shoving in Firefox issue for me.

Comment: I confirm that with Inkscape 1.2.2 (2022-12-01), selecting `Input/Output > SVG export > SVG 2 to 1.1` `> correct marker direction` and `> correct marker colors` preferences fixes the colour of arrowheads when importing into Pages 13.1 under MacOS 12.7.

Comment: @MartinC: You can request a merger of [your account](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/279034/martin-cr). See [this help entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Inkscape 1.2.2 on Windows and the SVG Export setting advice from other answers and links did not work.  I applied the "Use correct marker colors" and then tried multiple variations of settings colors, setting options and exporting, but nothing would fix it from within Inkscape.

Opening the exported SVG file in a text editor (it's just XML), revealed that it always saved the style color like

```
style="fill:context-stroke;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:context-stroke;stroke-width:0.6pt"
```

I replaced the `context-stroke` values with the actual color, like below.  This worked to render properly in the browser and other applications.

```
style="fill:#999999;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#999999;stroke-width:0.6pt"
```

I did this for each XML `<marker> ... <path ...>` combinations that define the start and/or ending arrow points.

From what I understand, this is precisely what the SVG Export option are supposed to do, but they apparently don't work (always or at all?).